# Opening the door of the house during salah

Tags: sharia

Suppose the husband is knocking at the door, and the wife is performing her obligatory salah, so she is unable to open the door which is opposite to qibla.

What is the Islamic ruling in such a case? Can she open the door, and continue salah after that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the hadith I remember hearing,

> Abu Dawood narrated that Aa'isha (may Allah be pleased with her), said, "The Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him), used to pray with the door closed, so I arrived and asked him to open it, so he came and opened it and returned to his prayer" (the narrator mentioned that the door was in the direction of the qibla).
>
> ~[IslamQA - Movement while praying and preventing someone from passing.](http://islamqa.info/en/14)

So yes it is allowed according to the above hadith, however note that in the hadith the Prophet salahu alayhi wa-salam doesn't change direction, and I imagine the house was small enough that the motions required were also small.

Ultimately, it is down with to decide if the action of opening the door will risk invalidating your salah, as you know we best how it effects  your kushor, how much movement is required and your perceived urgency in opening the door.

And Allahu Alim (Allah knows best)

Comment: is this about obligatory or Mustahab prayer?

Comment: @BattleOfKarbala That is way good question,  that I don't think I can answer with confidence at the moment.